# insert file containing php code into a variable as string

Tags: php, file, tags, include

I have this:

> ```
>   ob_start();                     ?>
>           <div class="" id="loading">
>                <?php echo file_get_contents($page["texto"]) ?> 
>           </div>      <?php
>
>   $content = ob_get_clean();
> ```

But I would like to have that template html in a separate file, just like:

```
$content = file_get_contents('cms/template.php');
```

Now this won't work because it has php tags inside and when retrieving the string it gets as

how can I achieve this without using a dirty hack like:

```
$pre = file_get_contents('part1');
$var = file_get_contents($page["texto"]);
$post = file_get_contents('part2');
```

And adding all them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's still hack, but unless you use a templating system like Twig you have no choice:

```
ob_start();
include 'cms/template.php';
$content = ob_get_clean();

echo $content;
```

[ob_start](https://www.php.net/ob_start) enables output buffering so nothing gets sent to the browser. We then include the file which will execute PHP normally. We then use [ob_get_clean](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php) to get the contents of the output buffer (which is your template file). and disable the output buffer, discarding it's contents, as we have the contents in `$content`.

Comment: That was so stupidly easy... It worked fine! 
I couldn't figure that mixing include and ob_ would work like that... I'm accepting your anwser in 7 mins

Comment: I don't consider that a hack. You're taking advantage of PHP's features. You have some text that needs to be processed and stored, but not displayed. The `ob_*` set of functions is perfect for that.

Comment: @TecBrat I know, it's pretty much the best solution we have. I just wish PHP had a function like include/require that returned output as a variable so we didn't have to do this.

Comment: Still much better than making it in three files. tyvm